# Tensorflow model selection ? Which model do I select?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have trained a network with and LSTM but I see that there is over fitting And have tried several combinations of LR/batch size /optimizers but most combinations give a similar graph.

I would like to know I Could use a model before 75k iterations.
And would You consider this model to be over fit?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually hard to say if this is overfitted - as you have really high variance in the training. It is probable, but not sure.

#### Which model to choose?

Usually you would create a validation dataset, where you test your networks performance, and you select the model (including set of hyperparameters) which yields the highest score. That's all. Without additional validation set it will be hard.

#### How to fit overfitting?

There are plenty of techniques, including:

- early stopping (you will need yet again - validaation set, to test when your network starts to overfit)
- adding priors

  - prior on the weights - like L2 regularization
  - prior over structure of the network - maybe you can limit the size of your network?
  - prior over data distribution - maybe you can augment your dataset in some way? Like - for images you can usually disort them a bit (rotate, translate) without losing label. For generic data usually noising them works fine
- ensembling - averaging multiple networks (either explicitly, or through dropout) reduces overfitting
- last but not least - gathering more data always helps (as in the limit empirical error converges to generalization).

Answer (score 0):

The technique you are suggesting is called [early stopping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_stopping) and many people have used it as a way to combat over fitting. Other things you could do would be to decrease the size of your network or to try and collect more data.